# In Firebase Flutter how do I access details of the logged in user using my custom class

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

The code for the model class is as shown below:

```
class UserAuthModel {

  String? uid;
  String? email;
  String? displayName;
  String? profilePic;

  UserAuthModel(this.uid, this.email, this.displayName, this.profilePic);

  UserAuthModel.fromFirebaseUser({User? user}) {
    this.uid = user!.uid;
    this.email = user.email;
    this.displayName = user.displayName;
    this.profilePic = user.photoURL;
  }
}
```

The code for the service class is shown below:

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth authInstance = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<UserAuthModel?> get currentUser => authInstance.authStateChanges().map(
        (User? firebaseUser) => (firebaseUser != null) ? UserAuthModel.fromFirebaseUser(user: firebaseUser) : null,
      );
}
```

The provider is defined as shown below:

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthService>(
          create: (_) => AuthService(),
        ),
      ],
```

This is how I'm trying to consume the provider within the code:

```
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    final loggedInUser = authService.currentUser;
```

But when I try to access the user details using the `currentUser` as shown below, I'm unable to do so, not sure why?

```
   print(loggedInUser.uid);
   print(loggedInUser.email);
   print(loggedInUser.displayName);
   print(loggedInUser.profilePic);
```

How can I access these details?

I don't see either the `uid, email, displayName or profilePic` to select as shown in the pic below:

[image]

Comment: you're not using Firestore anywhere in the actual code, so I removed that tag. Aside from that: what is keeping you from accessing the user details? Is there an error message?

Comment: Thansk @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not getting any error, but I don't see either the `uid, email, displayName or profilePic` to select. Let me take a screenshot and attach it to the question for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties you are looking for are defined on `UserAuthModel`. But your `loggedInUser` is declared as this as far as I can see:

```
Stream<UserAuthModel?> get currentUser
```

So the properties you can read from `loggedInUser` are properties of `Stream` and not of `UserAuthModel`.

#### Reading the user model once

To get the properties of the actual `UserAuthModel`, you can use the methods of the `Stream`. For example you can await the first `UserAuthModel` with:

```
var user = await loggedInUser.first
print(user.uid);
```

#### Listening/observing the user model

You can also listen for changes to the logged in user, so that you don't just get their initial state, but also any changes with:

```
loggedInUser.listen((user) {
  print(user.uid);
}
```

#### Showing the user model in your UI

And if you want to use the user in your UI, you'll typically wrap it in a `StreamBuilder`, which then handles the asynchronous behavior of the stream for you and gives you a `UserAuthModel` to work with.

I highly recommend reading the Flutter documentation on [asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams) and on [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to learn more about these concepts, as they're fundamental to working with cloud-hosted data in Flutter.

Comment: Thank you so much @FrankvanPuffelen for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a `Provider` if you want to extract the `currentUser` logic outside of your widgets. Something like this:

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  var _user;

  void listen() {
    try {
      UserService.listenUserDataChanges((dynamic user) {
        {
          _user = user;
          notifyListeners();
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  User get user {
    return _auth.currentUser;
  }

  dynamic get userData {
    return _user;
  }
}
```